# How to make Streamlit reloads every 5 seconds?

Tags: python, streamlit

I have to reload a Streamlit chart every 5 seconds, in order to visualize the new data in a XLSX report.
How to achieve this?

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import os

mainDir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
filePath = os.path.join(mainDir, "sources\\test.xlsx")
df = pd.read_excel(filePath)

option1 = 'Product'
option2 = 'Quantity'

df = df[[option1, option2]].set_index(option1)

st.write('Product Quantity')
st.area_chart(df)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Streamlit recognizes every time your **source code** changes. So, based on this premise, one way to achieving this is to create an empty "dummy.py" file, which will be imported by the main script and updated every 5 seconds by another script running simultaneously:

- create an empty "dummy.py" file inside the same folder of your main script;
- create a script called "refresher.py" in the same folder;

  - now put the following While loop inside your "refresher.py" file, in order to update the "dummy.py" with a random number (commented) every 5 seconds:

    ```
    from random import randint
    import time
    import os

    def refresher(seconds):
        while True:
            mainDir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
            filePath = os.path.join(mainDir, 'dummy.py')
            with open(filePath, 'w') as f:
                f.write(f'# {randint(0, 10000)}')
            time.sleep(seconds)

    refresher(5)
    ```
- add the following line to the script with your Streamlit chart code: """   from dummy import *   """
- run the "refresher.py" script;
- run the Streamlit script with your chart;
- Streamlit from now on will recognize any modifications in the "dummy.py file" as a modification in the source code;
- Once the web page is fully loaded, it will alert you the source file was changed. Click on " Alway rerun" and that's it.

Comment: When I run this my streamlit app just spins and never loads - perhaps the updates broke this?

Comment: @OrionTheHunter you probably missed the import """ from dummy import *  """. It still works on the version 0.66.0

Comment: It works on my local machine. But when I deployed it to prod, which receives 10k+ views a day, I just see the page loading.